# DPDK test application cannot found on redhat

Tags: linux, testing, redhat, dpdk

I met a issue with error shows(when deploy dpdk on redhat) :

**sudo: x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/test: command not found**

I am not sure what is the matter.

Now I cannot test dpdk, could you someone help me if you met this before.

There are some detailed information about my system below.

### FYI.

### Kernel version

3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64

---

[root@cnhzdhcp16557 usertools]# ./dpdk-setup.sh

### Build x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc

...

== Build app/test-crypto-perf

== Build app/test-eventdev

Build complete [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc]

Installation cannot run with T defined and DESTDIR undefined

---

### Insert IGB UIO module

Unloading any existing DPDK UIO module

Loading DPDK UIO module

---

### Insert VFIO module

Unloading any existing VFIO module

Loading VFIO module

chmod /dev/vfio

OK

---

### Insert KNI module

Unloading any existing DPDK KNI module

Loading DPDK KNI module

Press enter to continue ...

---

### Network devices using kernel driver

0000:00:19.0 'Ethernet Connection I217-V 153b' if=enp0s25 drv=e1000e unused=igb_uio *Active*

0000:02:00.0 'Centrino Advanced-N 6235 088e' if=wlo1 drv=iwlwifi unused=igb_uio

---

### Huge page information

AnonHugePages:     98304 kB

HugePages_Total:     128

HugePages_Free:      128

HugePages_Rsvd:        0

HugePages_Surp:        0

Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

---

### Run test application ($RTE_TARGET/app/test)

Enter hex bitmask of cores to execute test app on

Example: to execute app on cores 0 to 7, enter 0xff

bitmask: f

Launching app

**sudo: x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/test: command not found**

---

### Run testpmd application in interactive mode ($RTE_TARGET/app/testpmd)

Enter hex bitmask of cores to execute test app on

Example: to execute app on cores 0 to 7, enter 0xff

bitmask: f

Launching app

EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)

EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB

EAL: Probing VFIO support...

EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1

EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0

EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153b net_e1000_em

EAL: No probed ethernet devices

Interactive-mode selected

USER1: create a new mbuf pool : n=171456, size=2176,

socket=0

EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1

Cause: Creation of mbuf pool for socket 0 failed: Cannot allocate memory

---

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. I don't see any code here. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. ....

Comment: use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: But I'm thinking this Q is really more on topic for https://unix.stackexchange.com . You can use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Again, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test application should be build manually with `make test...` command. What you really want is the `testpmd` application to work. There are two issues:

1. `EAL: No probed ethernet devices` log means there are no NICs available for `testpmd`. You need to bind your NIC to `igb_uio` in order to use in with DPDK application.
2. `Cause: Creation of mbuf pool for socket 0 failed: Cannot allocate memory` log means there are no enough huge pages to allocate mempool. Indeed:

   HugePages_Free: 128
   Hugepagesize: 2048 kB

There are 128 pages 2M each, which makes 256M of available memory. While `testpmd` tries to allocate `create a new mbuf pool : n=171456, size=2176` which makes 171456 * 2176 = 373M, so it fails.

The solution would be to either allocate more huge pages or to run `testpmd` with `--total-num-mbufs` command line option.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I have solved the issue.